# Infinity and solution of $x+2=x$

Tags: infinity, fake-proofs

I know that if we divide both sides by $x$ the equation becomes $1+\frac{2}{x}={1} \implies  x=\frac{2}{0}$ which is undetermined.

According to wolfram alpha $\infty +2=\infty$ , logically speaking shouldn't we say that $x= \infty$?

Comment: If you subtract x from both sides, you get 2=0. Dividing both sides of an equation by a variable only makes sense when that variable has a definite (and finite) value...

Comment: When you divide by $x$, you make the assumption $x\neq 0$. Moreover, the equation $1+2/x = 1$ does not give $x=2/0$, it gives $2/x=0$, or $2=0$.  How do you determine that $x=\infty$?

Comment: Infinity is not a real number. If you adjoin something to the set of real numbers and call it infinity, you have the freedom to stipulate various properties of it and how arithmetic with it works - however your stipulations must be self-consistent. You cannot both add and subtract infinity if it satisfies infinity+1=infinity, for instance (you'd get 1=0). For most useful notions of infinity, you will necessarily have to force most arithmetic operations with it to be undefined, so you cannot blithely divide by it without justification. That said, you can force it to satisfy x+2=x.

Comment: Occasionally, when one is trying to find a limit of a sequence of positive terms, if blind manipulation leads to $x=x+2$, it is good evidence that the sequence blows up.

Comment: @ everyone thank you very much .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\infty$ is not a real number, it becomes rather difficult to do arithmetic with it. In fact, treating it as a real number means that we have to sacrifice some other property of arithmetic (for example, treating it as a real number leads to the statement that $2 = 0$, which we certainly don't want to have). Hence, we would simply say that no solution exists.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what kind of number $x$ is.  If $x$ is a [surreal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number), [ordinal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), or [real number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number), then there is no solution.  But if $x$ is a [cardinal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number), there are solutions such as $x = \aleph_k = \aleph_k + 2$ for any ordinal $k$.  Although there are no solutions of $x = x + 2$ in ordinal numbers, there are solutions of $x = 2 + x$, for example $x = \omega = 2 + \omega$.  $\aleph_k$ is an infinite cardinal number, and $\omega$ is an infinite ordinal number, and both are different types of infinity.

Comment: There is something called "dangerous knowledge" to a student. It's when you tell someone about a concept X, while their mathematical level is not sufficient in order to fully grasp and understand it. In some cases the student will agree that they don't understand anything, and back away (and might develop a fear of the subject, but also might develop a passion to understand it); but sometimes it can create a student which thinks they understand an idea, while they really don't. It can be very problematic to later correct these gaps (from my own personal experience as the latter).

Comment: My own experience is a delayed or at least retarded appreciation of some mathematics for the opposite reason, which happens when you are told a concept X isn't possible or isn't worth thinking about. Of course either method can have unanticipated effects!  But overall I'm sorry nobody taught me about different types of infinity in high school, instead I learned it on my own much later even though it was one of the mathematical subjects I've always been most interested in.

Comment: Dan, don't get me wrong. I am, after all, a set theorist. But I've seen how I fell because of such dangerous knowledge, and how long it took me to get myself back up (and fully understand something, because it took me so long to understand that I didn't understand it in the first place). In part the blame is with Wikipedia. Had MSE existed when I was an undergrad, I would probably had it worse. I do agree that it's good to tell people on less-popular alternatives, but it needs to be done carefully. *Very* carefully.

Comment: @Asaf I always appreciate your ME opinions, I have never taught math but I hope to some day be able to understand and apply your advice!

Comment: @DanBrumleve & everyone else thank you very much,@Dan :I really liked your answer but I choose the other one by votes.